# Yelp API to get reviews - only ever 3 records returned

Tags: php, yelp-fusion-api

I am developing a website where I want to get all the Yelp reviews for my business.

I tried fetching the reviews with the Yelp API.

```
 $client =  new  \Stevenmaguire\Yelp\v3\Client(array(
        'accessToken' => 'my-token',
        'apiHost' => 'api.yelp.com' // Optional, default 'api.yelp.com'
    ));

 $reviews = $client->getBusinessReviews($id);
```

But it return only 3 reviews. How can I get all the reviews?

Comment: I believe yelp api v3 by default returns 3 reviews only, For getting full details you need to upgrade to business. Can you try with older api versions ?

Comment: This endpoint returns up to three review excerpts for a given business ordered by Yelp's default sort order.

Comment: @Ajith thank you..will try after upgrading.